# Run away rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Link to doc - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-kEMMiB6mj3lt3DUSDvW3BmdGaADajbGUwD_oZVllWU/edit?usp=sharing

I have written a formula that scans a list of Slack threads, formats the threads into plain text, then counts the frequency of every word in the range of plain text.

The goal behind this formula is to search for 'trending' keywords that frequently pop up in a Slack channel.

As you can see there are a couple tabs, the Readme does a decent job explaining everything but I'll give the TLDR here:

The Data tab contains all of the imported Slack information. Data!E2 contains a messy formula of REGEXREPLACE functions that filter the data into plain text.

In the Keywords tab under Keywords!A2 you'll find the 'frequency' counting formula. Here it is:

```
​=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", Data!E3:E)," ")&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) where not(Col1 matches'"&JOIN("|", Stopwords!B1:B)&"') group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc limit 800 ",0))
```

​To clarify the formula searches the range Data!E3:E and JOINS all the words together with a space delimiter. Then, we SPLIT the string across a number of cells and TRANSPOSE the new row of cells into a column of cells found in Keywords!A3.

Lastly, a query is run to count all of the instances of each word and places each keyword's count into Keywords!B3. One thing to keep in mind is this query is run against a list of stopwords found under Stopwords!B1 in order to remove a good deal of text from the query that would not really need to be counted.

As you can see I am now receive a #REF! error. This wasn't always the case, for a while this formula worked as expected, words were listed in column A under Keywords and column B showed the frequency they appear. The other columns then could run their functions off this list and fill in the rest of the Keywords sheet.

I am curious though, I noted when I set the function range to Data!E3:3000 that every time the function ran it would add another ten or so rows to the range, so it would grow to E3:3018, E3:3032 etc etc. Then it broke and now says "Error Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows (13)."

If anyone could help me optimize this formula to run a bit better that would be amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that no one has replied earlier.  I just found this.

But I think your error is in column B of your Stopwords tab.  The formula there should be moved to B1, instead of partway down the page.  That is giving the REF! error, which then appears in your main formula when it references the Range B1:B.

Let me know if this helps.

And you may want to revise your formula to end with:

```
 label count(Col2) ''
```

which removes the header for the count(Col2) column.